# gem rMagick is not installing on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I am working on rails 4.2.7 app. The app was working fine few days ago but suddenly When i try to install bundle it gives error....'

```
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.15.4), and Bundler 
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.15.4' --source 
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.'
```

When i run "gem install rmagick -v '2.15.4" it gives error

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/shahroz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@hh-web- 
platform/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/ext/RMagick
/home/shahroz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190411- 
829-1e8ve9u.rb extconf.rb
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
checking for pkg-config... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.15.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of 
necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  
You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/shahroz/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 
   2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

   To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the 
   mkmf.log which can be found here:

    /home/shahroz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@hh-web- 
   platform/extensions/x86_64- 
   linux/2.2.0/rmagick-2.15.4/mkmf.log

   extconf failed, exit code 1

   Gem files will remain installed in /home/shahroz/.rvm/gems/ruby- 
   2.2.3@hh-web-platform/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
   Results logged to /home/shahroz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@hh-web- 
  platform/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
```

I tried the following commands but nothing worked for me,

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat 
libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev

sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
```

i want gem rmagick to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this and tell me if you served please

```
sudo apt install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command *did not work for me* it dropped and *abort* error.

```
sudo apt install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

what did work for me:

```
sudo apt install libmagickcore-dev
```

Installing them separatedly did the trick, not sure why.. banged my head 6 hours after realizing it.