# rmagick gem installing on Zorin OS

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick

I have this setup on a HP Pavilion Gaming laptop:

- Zorin OS 16.2
- asdf v0.11.1 for versioning ruby and node
- Ruby 3.2.2
- ImageMagick 7.1.1 installed from source

I'm trying to use rmagick Gem with Ruby 3.2.2.

When I run `gem install rmagick` it returns

```bash
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rmagick-5.2.0/ext/RMagick
/home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for brew... no
checking for pacman... no
checking for Ruby version >= 2.3.0... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.7.7)... no
checking for gcc... yes
checking for __GNUC__... yes
checking for MagickCore/MagickCore.h... yes
checking for rb_gc_adjust_memory_usage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... yes
checking for posix_memalign() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... yes
checking for malloc_usable_size() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... yes
checking for malloc_size() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... no
checking for _aligned_msize() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... no
checking for GetImageChannelEntropy() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... no
checking for SetImageGray() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... no
checking for SetMagickAlignedMemoryMethods() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,sys/types.h,MagickCore/MagickCore.h... no
checking for malloc.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile
======================================================================
Tue 30 May 23 21:00:30
This installation of RMagick 5.2.0 is configured for
Ruby 3.2.2 (x86_64-linux) and ImageMagick 7.1.1
======================================================================


Configured compile options: {:magick_version=>"7.1.1", :local_libs=>"  -L/usr/local/lib -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI", :cppflags=>"-I/home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/include  $(DEFS) $(cppflags)  -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7 -std=gnu99 -Wno-void-pointer-to-int-cast -Wno-void-pointer-to-enum-cast -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast", :ldflags=>"-L. -L/home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-as-needed  -L/usr/local/lib -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib", :defs=>["-DHAVE_MAGICKCORE_MAGICKCORE_H", "-DHAVE_RB_GC_ADJUST_MEMORY_USAGE", "-DHAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN", "-DHAVE_MALLOC_USABLE_SIZE", "-DHAVE_MALLOC_H", "-DRUBY_VERSION_STRING=\"ruby 3.2.2\"", "-DRMAGICK_VERSION_STRING=\"RMagick 5.2.0\"", "-DIMAGEMAGICK_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL_6_8_9=1", "-DIMAGEMAGICK_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL_6_9_0=1", "-DIMAGEMAGICK_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL_6_9_10=1", "-DIMAGEMAGICK_7=1", "-DIMAGEMAGICK_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL_7_0_8=1", "-DIMAGEMAGICK_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL_7_0_10=1"], :config_h=>"Makefile"}

current directory: /home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rmagick-5.2.0/ext/RMagick
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230530-25754-h6qqva sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230530-25754-h6qqva clean

current directory: /home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rmagick-5.2.0/ext/RMagick
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230530-25754-h6qqva sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230530-25754-h6qqva
compiling rmagick.c
compiling rmdraw.c
compiling rmenum.c
compiling rmfill.c
compiling rmilist.c
compiling rmimage.c
rmimage.c: In function ‘Image_gray_q’:
rmimage.c:7945:32: error: ‘IsGrayImage’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘DrawImage’?
 7945 |     return has_attribute(self, IsGrayImage);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                DrawImage
rmimage.c:7945:32: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
rmimage.c:7965:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 7965 | }
      | ^
rmimage.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-void-pointer-to-enum-cast’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-void-pointer-to-int-cast’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
make: *** [Makefile:248: rmimage.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rmagick-5.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/mauro/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.2.0/rmagick-5.2.0/gem_make.out
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I've tried to install imagemagick using apt following sugested solutions like the ones proposed in this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634219/gem-rmagick-is-not-installing-on-ubuntu-18-04) but I have dependencies problems when I run `sudo apt install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`

Hope you can guide me. Thanks in advance